# Пробелы при оформлении интервалов с градусами

Tags: пробелы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить в интервалах после многоточия пробел? Например, -20... -25 °С. У Мильчина в одном примере пробел стоит, а в другом нет. Или это различие связано со знаками (+ и -)?

И если нужно написать через тире, поставив только знак градуса ° без Цельсия, повторять ли его после каждого числа? Или ставить только в конце (например, 15–20°)? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Тоже у Мильчина, только в другом разделе (6.4.4), где про знаки математических действий (плюсы и минусы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь перед минусом уже нет пробела. Значит, до этого была опечатка. Так что «Сибирскому лесному журналу» в этом вопросе можно доверять :)

Comment: Ну вот, я же и говорил, что по логике выходит опечатка.)

Comment: **Aurora** "Так что «Сибирскому лесному журналу» в этом вопросе можно доверять" - доверять никому не надо, тем более - не самым крупным специалистам, да без крайней нужды. Лучше просто убедиться, что тут источник дал верную рекомендацию.

Answer (score 4):

Вот что пишет по этому поводу «[Сибирский лесной журнал](http://www.sibran.ru/journals/SLJ/rules)» в статье «Информация для авторов»:

> 8.7. В числовых интервалах, где числа имеют знак, вместо дефиса ставится многоточие: –5...–1 °С, +1...+5 °С.

Comment: Только там о пробеле не говорится.

Comment: Там есть примеры :)

Comment: Да, если в примерах правильно, что пробела нету, значит, мне интуиция правильно подсказала. Дело в том, что когда я писал ответ, то хотел сказать, что думаю, что пробел не нужен и в случае минусовой температуры, но потом подумал, что интуиция меня может подводить и с пробелом тоже смотрится не с полной очевидностью неправильно.

Answer (score 3):

Предположу, что разница связана не со знаками, а это просто опечатка или ошибка по небрежности. Иначе странно, что насчёт этого не пояснили. Но это если рассуждать логически. Как правильно, не знаю и боюсь ошибиться.

А со вторым вопросом всё очевидно. Если писать через тире, то так же как и в случае многоточия, повторять знак градуса не нужно независимо от того, стоит просто *°* или *°C.* Этот случай ничем не отличается от других единиц измерения. Например, мы пишем *10–12 м,* а не 10 м — 12 м.

Comment: Разве в 10-12 используется тире, а не дефис?

Comment: А разве там у меня тире? Я думал, что тире у меня при повторении метров только.

Comment: Посмотрел. в 10–12 у вас [en-dash](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E2%80%93), в 10 м — 12 м  [em-dash](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E2%80%94). Вроде бы то и другое считается тире, а дефис это «-» (hyphen-minus). Впрочем, я не эксперт по типографике, информацию взял отсюда: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150)

Comment: Изначально вопрос был к тому, что Вероника явно спрашивала только про тире, а вы про дефис не упомянули. Вот я и придрался )

Comment: Так правильно, тире и ставят, а не дефис.)

Comment: Артём Луговой, насчет дефисов и дашей. Эти вещи различаются только при компьютерной верстке, печатной, главным, образом продукции. Для экрана, тем более в окне ввода сообщения никто не заморачивается, если нет особых причин. В любом случае, если это существенно, можно (и даже нужно!) оговорить словами, о каком знаке идет речь, бог знает, как каким шрифтом он воспроизведется у читателя на экране. Реального m-dash'a нет ни в одном экранном шрифте, сам термин "среднее тире" используется только, когда короткое тире отлично графически от дефиса, а это и на печати-то редкость большая.

Comment: Да я сам не разбираюсь во всех тонкостях и для упрощения делю всё на тире (длинное) и дефис. А в данном случае когда я писал "10–12 м", то вроде скопировал чуть подлиньше знак у Вероники, поскольку мне показалось, что он у неё удачный по длине, а дефис (минус) смотрится странно. Правильность этого и подтвердилась потом статьёй Ника Волынкина (там предлагается среднее тире (которое я и поставил, как оказалось) или длинное использовать в числовых интервалах). :)